# Blank page when deploying Angular website on Netlify

Tags: javascript, angular, frameworks, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a project website using Angular 7 but it's showing a blank page. It works fine on a local host. I've wasted an entire day trying to solve it but with no success. Any ideas on what might be the issue? Thanks in advance. Here is the url to the website: https://m.alabamarket.com

Please find below the deploy log

```
3:57:30 PM: Build ready to start
3:57:33 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
3:57:33 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
3:57:33 PM: buildbot version: ef8d0929ed0baabafd8bbb7d0b021e1fc24180c0
3:57:33 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
3:57:33 PM: Starting to download cache of 176.4MB
3:57:35 PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.122552229s
3:57:35 PM: Starting to extract cache
3:57:40 PM: Finished extracting cache in 5.336044214s
3:57:40 PM: Finished fetching cache in 6.509703968s
3:57:40 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
3:57:40 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/RFQ
3:57:42 PM: Starting build script
3:57:42 PM: Installing dependencies
3:57:42 PM: Started restoring cached node version
3:57:44 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
3:57:45 PM: v10.16.0 is already installed.
3:57:46 PM: Now using node v10.16.0 (npm v6.9.0)
3:57:46 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
3:57:47 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
3:57:47 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
3:57:47 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
3:57:47 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
3:57:47 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
3:57:55 PM: npm
3:57:55 PM:  WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
3:57:55 PM: npm WARN
3:57:55 PM:  notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
3:57:55 PM: audited 19009 packages in 6.342s
3:57:55 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
3:57:55 PM: NPM modules installed
3:57:56 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
3:57:56 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
3:57:56 PM: unset GOOS;
3:57:56 PM: unset GOARCH;
3:57:56 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
3:57:56 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
3:57:56 PM: go version >&2;
3:57:56 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
3:57:56 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
3:57:56 PM: Installing missing commands
3:57:56 PM: Verify run directory
3:57:56 PM: Executing user command: ng build
3:58:12 PM: Date: 2019-07-10T14:58:12.768Z
3:58:12 PM: Hash: 50d6e3d977e5b87155d3
3:58:12 PM: Time: 12495ms
3:58:12 PM: chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 998 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:12 PM: chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills) 546 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:12 PM: chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
3:58:12 PM: chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 671 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:12 PM: chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 4.53 MB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: Date: 2019-07-10T14:58:23.505Z
3:58:23 PM: Hash: 0b3e57de5bd2dd477a95
3:58:23 PM: Time: 10658ms
3:58:24 PM: Starting post processing
3:58:23 PM: chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 988 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 248 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 671 kB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 4.35 MB [initial] [rendered]
3:58:23 PM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
3:58:23 PM: Caching artifacts
3:58:23 PM: Started saving node modules
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving node modules
3:58:23 PM: Started saving pip cache
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving pip cache
3:58:23 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Started saving go dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
3:58:23 PM: Build script success
3:58:28 PM: Minifying bundle
3:58:23 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'src'
3:58:23 PM: Creating deploy tree 
3:58:24 PM: 0 new files to upload
3:58:24 PM: 0 new functions to upload
3:58:29 PM: Minifying bundle
3:58:33 PM: Minifying bundle
3:58:34 PM: Minifying bundle
3:58:35 PM: Minifying bundle
3:58:44 PM: Post processing done
3:58:44 PM: Site is live
3:58:49 PM: Finished processing build request in 1m16.150366863s
```

Please find the content of angular.json below:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mobile": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mobile",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./src/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mobile:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mobile:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mobile:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mobile:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "mobile:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "mobile"
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any trace of Angular or "app-root" in the JS file referenced in the HTML.

Comment: How?@niorad but It works perfectly on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

if u look at the source their is no reference to any js file either polyfill or main, make sure your dist folder contains all the js files if not try to rebuild and redeploy.

if problem persists please share angular.json file

Comment: I have include the contents of the angular.json in the question